# Capturing multiline character groups

Tags: java, regex, multiline

Regex pros, i have a GoogleTest --gtest_list_tests output which i need to parse to get each test suite and case. The output has the following format:

```
TestSuite1.  
    TestCase1  
    TestCase2  
TestSuite2.  
    TestCase1  
    TestCase2  
    TestCase3
```

And so on. I need to have a java regex pattern that would capture each test suite with its cases. For the above input i would need to have group 1 as

```
TestSuite1.  
    TestCase1  
    TestCase2
```

and group 2 as

```
TestSuite2.  
    TestCase1
    TestCase2  
    TestCase3
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make it work. For now i am using this pattern:

```
(.+\\.\\n(?:\\s+.+\\n)+)+
```

which doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the line terminator `$` if you set the multiline flag:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException
{
    String s = "TestSuite1.\n" + 
               "    TestCase1\n" + 
               "    TestCase2\n" + 
               "TestSuite2.\n" + 
               "    TestCase1\n" + 
               "    TestCase2\n" + 
               "    TestCase3";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\.$(\\s+\\w+$)+", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(s);

    while (matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
        System.out.println("-----------");
    }
}

Output:

TestSuite1.
    TestCase1
    TestCase2
-----------
TestSuite2.
    TestCase1
    TestCase2
    TestCase3
-----------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to capture grouped data:

```
[^.\s]+\.(?:\R\h+.+)+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/skX2E4/1)

**Explanation:**

- `[^.\s]+`: Match any character that is not a dot and not whitespace
- `\.`: followed by a dot
- `(?:\R\h+.+)+` Match 1 or more lines starting with 1+ whitespace for test cases

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could make the `\n` optional and omit the last quantifier `+`

[`(.+\.\n(?:\s+.+\n?)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/UFbSgV/1)

That would match

```
(       # Capturing group
  .+    # Any character one more times
  \.    # Match a dot
  \n    # Match a newline
  (?:   # Non capturing group
    \s+ # One or more whitespace characters
    .+  # Any character one more times
    \n? # An optional newline
  )+    # Close non capturing group and repeat o 1 or more times
)       # Close capturing group
```

If you don't want to capture it in group 1, you could use:

[`.+\.\n(?:\s+.+\n?)+`](https://regex101.com/r/UFbSgV/2)